# Bash to check for valid Git commit hash?

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble writing a simple Bash script that will check if an input argument is a valid Git commit hash which for me means it's either "HEAD" or a 7-character alphanumeric string.  So far I have this 'deploy.sh' script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
GIT_COMMIT=$1
if [[ "$GIT_COMMIT" != "HEAD" && ! "$GIT_COMMIT" =~ [^a-zA-Z0-9] ]]
then
  printf "Error!  Not a valid Git commit hash.\n"
  exit 1
else
  printf "Git commit hash is valid.\n"
  exit 0
fi
```

These should be valid:

```
./deploy.sh HEAD
./deploy.sh a1b2c3d
./deploy.sh BBc8c4e
./deploy.sh 1234d8
```

Things like this would be invalid:

```
./deploy.sh a1b2c3#
./deploy.sh foobarbaz
```

Comment: why not checking which branches you currently have instead? ```git branch | egrep -vi 'head|master' | grep $1 | wc -l``` and if not 0, then continue?

Comment: What trouble do you have with your script? What exactly is your question? Does the script work as intended? You are aware that you do `GIT_BRANCH=$1` and then you do `"$GIT_COMMIT"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GIT_COMMIT=$1
if [[ "$GIT_COMMIT" != "HEAD" && ! "$GIT_COMMIT" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,7}$ ]]
then
  printf "Error!  Not a valid Git commit hash.\n"
  exit 1
else
  printf "Git commit hash is valid.\n"
  exit 0
fi
```

This seems to work on above mentioned usecase, however I am not exactly sure if I have correctly understood the ask.

Comment: Thank you.  Actually this is pretty close.  I see some things I was missing.  However, it doesn't quite catch everything.  E.g., if I input "1a2bc?d" as the hash, my zshell complains saying "zsh: no matches found."  And if the hash is only six characters long, e.g. "foobar", it doesn't catch that.  I need to look up if "{1,7}" means between one and seven characters.  If so, then I need to look up how to specify exactly seven characters.

Comment: Hi Ray, If you want to check for exactly 7 characters, you can use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$`, and for input "1a2bc?d", can you please try providing this in double quotes and see what happens?

Comment: {7} fixes the length problem and enclosing the hash string in double quotes fixes the zsh problem.  I will just have to remember to always enclose the hash string in double quotes if it's not "HEAD".

Comment: You only need to quote the hash string when you want to give it an invalid hash, so that's convenient.